# Importar Componente React Native Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Buenas tengo una HomeScreen y le quiero añadir importar un componente Header.
Estoy aprendiendo no sean duros

```js
export default function Header(){
    return (
    <View style = { styles.header}>
        <MaterialIcons name='menu' size={28} onPress={} stle={style.icon}/>
        <View>
        <Text style ={styles.headerText}>Rate Me</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
);
}
```

Este es mi componente que se encuentra en Components/header.js
Y esta es mi main

```js
import  Header  from ' Components/header';

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Header />
            <Text>hehe</Text>

            <Button
            title = "Go!"
            onPress= {() => navigation.navigate('Detalle', { title : 'aleks95', user_name:'Alex'})}
            />
        </View>

    )
}

HomeScreen.navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: ()=> <Header navigation={navigation} title='rasdf'/>,
    headerRight:(
        <Button onPress={() => alert('hola')}
                title="Go!"
                color = "#000000"/>
    ),
    headerStyle:{
        backgroundColor: '#D9FFFE'
    },
    headerTintColor: '#0000000',
    headerTitleStyle:{
        fontWeight:'200'
    }
}
```

A continuación adjunto el arbol del proyecto 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo tengo mal me gustaría saber el que...Gracias!

Comment: Te da algún error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por lo que veo estás ingresando mal **la ruta en el import.**, te falta el ./ al inicio.

Probá poniendo:

```js
import  Header  from '../Components/Header';
```

Explicación: con un solo punto y barra **"./archivo"** marcás la ruta de un archivo ubicado en la misma carpeta que el componente desde donde lo importás.

Con dos puntos y barra **"../carpeta/archivo"** retrodecés un nivel en la ruta (sería como ir atrás en el navegador).

Espero que te sirva, cualquier cosa comentame.
Saludos!

Comment: He probado lo que me has dicho y no funciona...

Comment: Probaste tanto con un punto ("./") como con dos puntos ("../") ? Si querés mostrame una captura de tu árbol de carpetas y lo solucionamos.

Comment: He añadido la foto del arbol a ver si ayuda..haha

Comment: He hecho un npm install y ha funcionado! gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Debes escribir en tu archivo App.js

```
import  Header  from './Components/header';
```